# Min And Max Date With Date Format In Elementor Form Not Working

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using Min and Max date in the Elementor Form. The Min and Max date are working fine but When I add the Date Format, the Min & Max date is not working and Date Format is working.

My Min & Max Date Code Added In `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( window ).load( function( $ ){
        var limitFlatPicker;
        var afterTwoDays;
        var afterEightDays;
        limitFlatPicker = limitFlatPicker || {};
        limitFlatPicker = {
            defaultSettings: {
                selector: '.flatpickr-input',
                minDate: true,
                maxDate: true,
            },
            settings: {},
            init: function( options ) {
                this.settings = jQuery.extend( this.defaultSettings, options );
                if ( this.settings.minDate || this.settings.maxDate ) {
                    this.waitForFlatpicker( this.callback );
                }
            },
            waitForFlatpicker: function( callback ) {
                if ( typeof window.flatpickr !== 'function' ) {
                    setTimeout( function() { limitFlatPicker.waitForFlatpicker( callback ) }, 100 );
                }
                callback();
            },
            modifyPicker: function( picker, settings ) {
                flatpickr( picker ).set( settings );
            },
            callback: function() {
                var self;
                self = limitFlatPicker;
                jQuery( self.settings.selector ).each( function() {
                    var picker;
                    picker = jQuery( this )[0],
                    pickerSettings = {};

                    if ( self.settings.minDate ) {
                        pickerSettings['minDate'] = self.settings.minDate;
                    }
                    if ( self.settings.maxDate ) {
                        pickerSettings['maxDate'] = self.settings.maxDate;
                    }
                    self.modifyPicker( picker, pickerSettings );
                } );
            }
        }

            limitFlatPicker.init( {
                minDate: new Date(),
                selector: '#form-field-form_field_date',
            });         
            
    } );
</script>

<?php
},11);
```

But When I add the Date Format Code In `functions.php`, the Min & Max date is not working but Date Format is working:

```
add_action('wp_footer', function () {
       ?>
      <script>
      jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ){
            setTimeout( function(){
                  $('.flatpickr-input').each(function(){ flatpickr( $(this)[0] ).set('dateFormat', 'd/m/Y');});
            }, 1000 );
      });
      </script>
      <?php
},13);
```

So, I want to add the Min and Max date with the Date Format.

I also tried to add this in the above code but it is not working:

```
 limitFlatPicker.init( {
            minDate: new Date(),
            dateFormat: 'd/m/Y',
            selector: '#form-field-form_field_date',
        });
```

Any help is much apprecaited.

Comment: Can yuo share the URL of the page this is running on? It looks like the dateFormat parameter you have is correct. Did you try something simpler as a test, maybe with "d-m-Y" without the / character?

Comment: @mozboz. Did you check my code? problem is when i am adding the date format code, the min date stops working else the min date is working fine.

Comment: The last code you pasted with dateFormat looks right to me, but I'm just going by the Elementor docs. You should probably talk to Elementor - you may have found a bug in their code

Comment: @mozboz, Okay, that code is working but it is not working with min date code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [this `flatpickr`](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr), right?

*So I don't use Elementor and therefore, I haven't tested this with Elementor* or an Elementor form. However, from what I could see, all you need to do to make both the `minDate` and `dateFormat` work, is add this:

```js
if ( self.settings.dateFormat ) {
    pickerSettings.dateFormat = self.settings.dateFormat;
}
```

above this line:

```js
self.modifyPicker( picker, pickerSettings );
```

Because your Min & Max Date Code is currently only accepting certain (or more precisely, just two) custom settings, namely `minDate` and `maxDate`; hence, for other settings, you'd need to manually add them just as in the above example.

And that limitation can of course be removed, but I'm assuming there's a good reason why you (or the script's author) designed the script like that, so I'll let it be so. :)

So with the above addition (`pickerSettings.dateFormat`), the following `dateFormat` should now work:

```js
limitFlatPicker.init( {
    minDate: new Date(),
    selector: '#form-field-form_field_date',
    dateFormat: 'd/m/Y' // this should now work with minDate
});
```

### Additional Notes

1. JS tip: Instead of the array notation, you should use the dot notation, e.g. `pickerSettings.minDate` and not `pickerSettings['minDate']`.
2. Another JS tip (for `flatpickr` **v4**): The `true` as in `maxDate: true` would result in a JS error in the console (because `true` is not a valid date), so you should just use `maxDate: ''`. Well, `''` isn't a valid date, but empty values are ignored by `flatpickr`. (i.e. exempted from being *parsed into a date*)

### Update

So in the comment you asked: "*Can you please tell how the add `disableMobile: "true"` in this code?*"

And as I said in the original answer, you basically just need to add the following `if` block above the `self.modifyPicker( picker, pickerSettings );`:

```js
if ( undefined !== self.settings.<setting name> ) {
    pickerSettings.<setting name> = self.settings.<setting name>;
}
```

Or as I also said, you can remove the limitation (i.e. *make it **easy*** to set your custom settings for `flatpickr`) and here's one way of doing so: just replace the entire `callback: function() { ... }` with this:

```js
callback: function() {
    var self = limitFlatPicker;
    $( self.settings.selector ).each( function() {
        self.modifyPicker( this, jQuery.extend( {}, self.settings, {
            selector: null,
        } ) );
    } );
}
```

And regarding the `disableMobile` setting, I don't know if setting it to `true` (it's a *boolean* `true`, not the string `'true'`, although that would also work) will work with your theme or form because it all depends on the theme and plugins you're using. So you'll just have to try & test that setting on your own. However, you should check the [mobile support](https://flatpickr.js.org/mobile-support/) info on the `flatpickr` site and you can find all the *available settings and the proper value for each setting* [here](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/).

### Update 2

Actually, there's no need to call the `modifyPicker()` method from the `callback()` method, so in that `callback()`, just call `flatpickr()` like so:

```js
callback: function() {
    var self = limitFlatPicker;
    $( self.settings.selector ).each( function() {
        flatpickr( this, jQuery.extend( {}, self.settings, {
            selector: null,
        } ) );
    } );
}
```

Or with your original code — but after adding both the `pickerSettings.dateFormat` and `pickerSettings.disableMobile`, use `flatpickr( picker, pickerSettings );` and not `self.modifyPicker( picker, pickerSettings );`.

And that (i.e. calling `flatpickr()` directly) should fix this: "*The main problem is that the `dateFormat` is working correctly in Desktop but in mobile it is not working.*".

Additionally, I noticed a major issue with your `waitForFlatpicker()` method, so you should instead use the following `init()` and `waitForFlatpicker()` code:

```js
init: function( options ) {
    // [1]: Pass {} as the first arg so that this.defaultSettings doesn't get modified.
    this.settings = jQuery.extend( {}, this.defaultSettings, options );

    if ( this.settings.minDate || this.settings.maxDate ) {
        // [2]: Pass the 'options' and not this.callback
        this.waitForFlatpicker( options );
    }
    // there should be an 'else' here, but I assumed it's not necessary...
},
// [3]: The first arg is 'options' and not 'callback'
waitForFlatpicker: function( options ) {
    if ( typeof window.flatpickr !== 'function' ) {
        setTimeout( function() { limitFlatPicker.waitForFlatpicker( options ); }, 100 );
    }
    else { // [4]: Make sure there's an 'else'.
        this.settings = jQuery.extend( {}, this.defaultSettings, options );
        this.callback();
    }
},
```

#### Working Demo (on JS Fiddle)

Not an Elementor form, but you'd see the `minDate`, `dateFormat` and `disableMobile` all working good [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ally/pmt8Lre4/) — the first input should look the same on both desktop and mobile devices.

And by the way, I used a different `callback()` code there and you'd want to use it if you want to allow only certain `flatpickr` settings with the `limitFlatPicker.init()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked.

Comment: I have removed that: $('.flatpickr-input').each(function(){ flatpickr( $(this)[0] ).set('dateFormat', 'd/m/Y');}

Comment: There is one problem that, if I am using in mobile, It has changed the behavior. So, Can you help me with that.

Comment: Can you please tell how the add `disableMobile: "true"` in this code?

Comment: Can you please help men with that because it is showing different behavior on mobile.

Comment: `if ( self.settings.disableMobile ) {
    pickerSettings.disableMobile = "true";
}` Will this work for mobile?

Comment: @RahulKumar maybe yes, maybe no, but I hope the "Update" part helps.

Comment: Can you please add the callback with the code because when I am adding that, it is not working?

Comment: The main problem is that the dateFormat is working correctly in Desktop but in mobile it is not working.

Comment: Like I said, just replace the entire `callback: function() { ... }` in your code as in the question - there's only one `callback: function() {}` block in your code - with the code I gave in the answer.

Comment: Okay. I have replaced it but where to that self.settings? If I replaced it then date format wont work.

Comment: What do you mean by "where to that self.settings"? But with the above `callback()` stuff, just pass the `flatpickr` settings you need like so: `limitFlatPicker.init( { minDate: new Date(), selector: '#form-field-form_field_date', dateFormat: 'd/m/Y', disableMobile: true });`. And regarding the `flatpickr`'s mobile support, it's already explained [here](https://flatpickr.js.org/mobile-support/), so just read and understand the limitations, etc. But have a look at [this fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rxm914eL/) - and btw, I used a different `callback()` code there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will mark this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have marked it.

Comment: Thanks! And hopefully the "Update 2" helps? :)